# How to send CSRF header with axios?

Tags: csrf, csrf-protection, axios

I am using axios in a Vue environment to talk to a web serivce written in Symfony. Each request needs an `X-Auth-Token` header to be set. The value is stored in an `auth_token` cookie.

The axios instance is configured using

```
xsrfCookieName: 'auth_token',
xsrfHeaderName: 'X-Auth-Token'
```

but even though `document.cookie` reveals `"auth_token=5e51c7d2..."`, the requests sent by axios do not have the `X-Auth-Token` header set and thus are hitting a `403 Forbidden`. If I manually set the header, everything works, but I thought the two options are supposed to handle that themselves. Am I doing something wrong? Unfortunately, I cannot provide a fiddle as I am talking to a private API.

Comment: Same problem using default cookie and header names.

Answer (score 1):

I came with the same problem with you and finally I solved it. 
My situation is that my cookie domain is not the same as the the page where I use axios to send request, so axios can't find the cookie.
It seems that axios find cookie based on the current browser domain.
Hopes to help you.